# MySQL Help Cleaning Total Counts

Tags: mysql, sql

Having an issue with a JOIN statement.

I'm trying to get a total per name, and not the current 1 with a ton of other same name records

```
SELECT a.`name`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(b.`id`) 
    FROM `host1_hosting` AS b 
    WHERE b.`id` = c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_hosting_idb`) AS HostingCount
FROM `host1_servers` AS a
LEFT JOIN `host1_servers_host1_hosting_1_c` AS c ON c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_servers_ida` = a.`id`
ORDER BY a.`name`
```

## Example Returned

Name HostingCount

Name 1

Name 1

Name 1

Where it should be:

Name 3

I'm sure this is simple, but it's early monday, and I'm foggy

## Query 2

```
SELECT a.`name`, COUNT(d.`id`)
FROM `host1_servers` AS a
JOIN `host1_servers_host1_hosting_1_c` AS c ON c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_servers_ida` = a.`id`
JOIN `host1_hosting` AS d ON d.`id` = c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_hosting_idb`
ORDER BY a.`name`
```

Gets me 1 name record, but a total of all `COUNT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query needs a `group by`:

```
SELECT a.`name`, COUNT(d.`id`)
FROM `host1_servers` AS a
JOIN `host1_servers_host1_hosting_1_c` AS c ON c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_servers_ida` = a.`id`
JOIN `host1_hosting` AS d ON d.`id` = c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_hosting_idb`
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY a.`name`;
```

Without the `GROUP BY`, MySQL interprets the query as an aggregation query to produce one row.  The `count()` is the overall count.  The column `name` is chosen arbitrarily from one of the rows (using a MySQL extension that wouldn't work in any other database).

EDIT:

If you want to keep all names from the first table and do the count, use `left outer join`:

```
SELECT a.`name`, COUNT(d.`id`)
FROM `host1_servers` a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `host1_servers_host1_hosting_1_c` c
     ON c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_servers_ida` = a.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `host1_hosting` d
     ON d.`id` = c.`host1_servers_host1_hosting_1host1_hosting_idb`
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY a.`name`;
```

Comment: Ok.  But now I don't have any records from a.name that may not have a count